# Python 2.7, TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

Seems like my SQL Request ended in:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Could you tell me what i did wrong here?

PS: I renamed the test1.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO dedi(test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' , '%s' , '%s'  , '%s' , '%s'  , '%s', '%s', '%s' , '%s' , '%s' ,'%s' ,'%s' , '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' , '%s' , '%s' , '%s'  )" % \
("Test", "flags/Test.png", "Test",  data[servcount][9] , data[servcount][8]  ,  +data[servcount][8]  ,  data[servcount][0]   , data[servcount][1]  ,  data[servcount][2]   ,  data[servcount][3] , "" , 0 ,  data[servcount][4]  ,  data[servcount][5] ,  data[servcount][7]  , 1 , 1, "", 0 , "", 1 , 0 , 1 , "" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `+` in front of one of your parameters (the 6th in the tuple):

```
+data[servcount][8]
```

Remove that `+`.